# How to reorder columns according to a list of new positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of dimensions (7096, 94), each index has a name.
I want to reorder the columns with that list of positions/locations :

```
[92, 57, 73, 81, 62, 64, 18, 93, 63, 89, 56, 72, 78, 26, 28, 79, 40, 54, 55, 53, 27, 21, 70, 25,
```

51,  7, 36, 23, 15, 59, 71,  0,  5, 91, 39, 67, 90, 77, 86,  2, 61, 69, 82, 46, 47, 45, 85, 75,
 83,  6, 88, 65, 34, 52,  4,  8, 29, 38, 35, 33, 60, 84, 80, 49, 24, 13,  3, 14, 12, 68, 16, 17,
 41, 31, 10, 87, 32, 11, 20, 76, 43, 66, 48, 37, 44, 74, 42, 22, 58,  1, 19, 50, 30,  9]

Comment: Do you want to only change the columns or the data as well?

Comment: Yes swap the column data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cols = [92, 57, 73, 81, 62, 64, 18, 93, 63, 89, 56, 72, 78, 26, 28, 79, 40, 54, 55, 53, 27, 21, 70, 25, 51, 7, 36, 23, 15, 59, 71, 0, 5, 91, 39, 67, 90, 77, 86, 2, 61, 69, 82, 46, 47, 45, 85, 75, 83, 6, 88, 65, 34, 52, 4, 8, 29, 38, 35, 33, 60, 84, 80, 49, 24, 13, 3, 14, 12, 68, 16, 17, 41, 31, 10, 87, 32, 11, 20, 76, 43, 66, 48, 37, 44, 74, 42, 22, 58, 1, 19, 50, 30, 9]

cols = [df.columns[c] for c in cols]
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: Thank you 'df.columns = cols' worked. However, the issue with this method is that i lose my column names. Is there a way to keep that integrity?

Comment: 'df = df[cols]' gives me KeyError: '[92 57 73 81 62 64 18 93 63 89 56 72 78 26 28 79 40 54 55 53 27 21 70 25\n 51  7 36 23 15 59 71  0  5 91 39 67 90 77 86  2 61 69 82 46 47 45 85 75\n 83  6 88 65 34 52  4  8 29 38 35 33 60 84 80 49 24 13  3 14 12 68 16 17\n 41 31 10 87 32 11 20 76 43 66 48 37 44 74 42 22 58  1 19 50 30  9] not in index'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to feed column indices directly:

```
cols = [92, 57, 73, 81, 62, 64, 18, ...]
df = df.iloc[:, cols]
```